# How to assign img tag under id with added increments

Tags: jquery

Quick question! How do I specify `<img>` under a unique id that is incrementally specified in a for loop? I do not know which key words to use to find a solution to this silly question, which is why I am here.

```
//What should I do after + i            
html2canvas($("#code" + i "<img>"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL();
        doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', x, 10, 10, 10);
        deferred.resolve();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`m not sure what your intentions are. From what I see you want to select the img tag under #code1, #code2 etc.

I imagine your code looks something like:

```
<div class="code1">
    <img alt="" title="" href="" />
</div>
<div class="code2">
    <img alt="" title="" href="" />
</div>
...
```

In that case you could select the image tags by doing so in the loop: `$("#code"+i+" img")`